# How do i sort an array in a function using pointer notation and the bubble sort algorithm in C

Tags: c, function, sorting, pointers, bubble-sort

I'm trying to sort `6` numbers input by the user using a bubble sort algorithm. My program has to be modular so I've written the program as a separate function but I keep getting two errors and I have no idea how to correct them.

`Error 1.` `Lvalue required in function sort_Nums(int *)`

`Error 2.` `Expression syntax in function sort_Nums(int *)`

Here's my code:

```
void sort_Nums(int*picked_nums)
{
    int i,step,temp;

    for(step=0; step<SIZE-1; ++step)
        for(i=0; i<SIZE-step-1; ++i)
        {
            if(*(picked_nums+i) > *(picked_nums+i)+1)
            {
                temp=*(picked_nums+i);
                *(picked_nums+i) = *(picked_nums+i)+1;
                *(picked_nums+i)+1 = temp;
            }
        }

        printf("The numbers you chose in order are:\n");
        for(i=0; i=<SIZE; ++i)
        {
            printf("%d\n", *(picked_nums+i));
        }   

        printf("Press any key to return to main menu");
        getchar();
    }
```

Thanks in advance and I am sorry if this is a stupid question and its just a syntax error or something but I've been coding for `9` hours almost now and this assignment is due tomorrow so this is a kind of last resort thing.

Comment: `for(i=0;i=<10;++i)`  really?

Comment: You should start using brackets. By the way I mean This `=<`

Comment: This =>> `*(picked_nums + (i + 1 ) ` is what you need, I think.

Comment: I normally do but i was basing the algorithm off notes from college and my algorithms lecturer codes strangely

Comment: Play with this [DEMO](https://ideone.com/2tYx6P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi your `if` condition  `if(*(picked_nums+i)>*(picked_nums+i)+1)`
  is wrong it should be `if(*(picked_nums+i)>*(picked_nums+i+1))`. As per bubble short logic you need to compare with next element in the array. Like

```
if (arr[1] > arr[2] )
```

and you are doing

```
if (arr[1] > arr[1] + 1 ) which is wrong.
```

Suppose arr[1] = 4  and arr[2]=3

with the below `if` condition it should swipe

`if (arr[1] > arr[1+1] )` because it is `if (4 > 3)` which is true

But your if condition is doing like below

if (arr[1] > arr[1] + 1)  which is equal to `if (4 > 3+1 )` which is false

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the errors and the code works other than an additional 1 in the output at the end of the sorted numbers

Edit: fixed by changing the for(i=0;i<=SIZE;++i) to for(i=0;i<SIZE;++i)

Answer (score 0):

Here you are adding `1` to the value, not to the pointer, and the second line causes the Lvalue error:

```
*(picked_nums+i)=*(picked_nums+i)+1;
*(picked_nums+i)+1=temp;
```

Corrected code would be like this:

```
*(picked_nums+i)=*(picked_nums+i+1);
*(picked_nums+i+1)=temp;
```

Comment: `I'd recommend using array syntax` Why would you recommend that if the OP says explicit that he need that Pointer notation?  ==>> `How do i sort an array in a function using pointer notation` Have you even read the OPs title?